# Razor files automatically excluded from watch & build in Visual Studio 2019 preview

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2019, blazor, blazor-server-side

When I add a new `.RAZOR` file it will automatically be excluded from the 'watch' and have no build action.

I need to manually edit the .CSPROJ file to remove the exclusion and remove the build actions settings.

**Tooling + extensions used:**

- Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2019 Preview (Version 16.8.0 Preview 5.0)
- Resharper Ultimate (2020.2.4)
- Web compiler (1.12.394) (Enabled/Disabled doesn't matter)

My current CSPROJ File, how it works:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
        <UserSecretsId>**</UserSecretsId>
        <DockerDefaultTargetOS>Linux</DockerDefaultTargetOS>
        <TypeScriptToolsVersion>4.0.5</TypeScriptToolsVersion>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <Content Remove="compilerconfig.json" />
        <None Include="compilerconfig.json" />
        <_ContentIncludedByDefault Remove="wwwroot\css\site.css" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <Watch Include="**\*.razor" />
        <Watch Include="**\*.css" />
        <Watch Include="**\*.ts" />
        <TypeScriptCompile Include="*.ts" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Blazorise.Icons.FontAwesome" Version="0.9.2-rc1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Blazorise.Material" Version="0.9.2-rc1" />
        <PackageReference Include="BuildWebCompiler" Version="1.12.394" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild" Version="4.0.3">
            <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
            <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
        </PackageReference>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Containers.Tools.Targets" Version="1.10.9" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

When I add a razor file (StackOverflowTest) my CSPROJ file looks like this

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
        <UserSecretsId>**</UserSecretsId>
        <DockerDefaultTargetOS>Linux</DockerDefaultTargetOS>
        <TypeScriptToolsVersion>4.0.5</TypeScriptToolsVersion>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <Content Remove="compilerconfig.json" />
        <Content Remove="Pages\StackOverflowTests.razor" /> <!--NEW-->
        <None Include="compilerconfig.json" />
        <None Include="Pages\StackOverflowTests.razor" /> <!--NEW-->
        <_ContentIncludedByDefault Remove="wwwroot\css\site.css" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <Watch Include="**\*.razor" />
        <Watch Include="**\*.css" />
        <Watch Include="**\*.ts" />
        <TypeScriptCompile Include="*.ts" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup> <!--NEW-->
      <Watch Remove="Pages\StackOverflowTests.razor" /> 
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Blazorise.Icons.FontAwesome" Version="0.9.2-rc1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Blazorise.Material" Version="0.9.2-rc1" />
        <PackageReference Include="BuildWebCompiler" Version="1.12.394" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild" Version="4.0.3">
            <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
            <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
        </PackageReference>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Containers.Tools.Targets" Version="1.10.9" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

**Edit:**

I've found that the following piece of code triggers this behaviour. Yet I'm unsure how to keep having a watch and not have this behaviour.

```xml
    <ItemGroup>
        <Watch Include="**\*.razor" />
        <Watch Include="**\*.css" />
        <Watch Include="**\*.ts" />
    </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Why do you have TypeScript rules in your build?

Comment: Because I've wanted to try out Typescript with the JS interop. I've found the 'culprit' what triggers this in a new project. You can see it in my edit.

It's basically this. https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/9922

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You no longer need to specify the .razor watch.

```xml
  <Watch Include="**\*.razor" />
```

Removing this line of code will stop the behaviour and still results in these filetypes to be watched.